Excluding particular style while performing a search and replace operation in Microsoft Word
I got the following macro which does not work as planned. The idea is to use an array to perform multiple find and replace operations everywhere in the text except for paragraphs with a particular style (Heading_14pt). In other words to exclude this heading from the search area.
I can't figure out why it starts an endless loop and does not stop. Please help!
Sub FindAndReplace_Not_Heading_14pt()
    Dim rngContent As Range
    Dim rngStyle As Paragraph
    Dim ArrFnd As Variant
    Dim ArrRep As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    ReDim ArrFnd(1 To 17)
    ReDim ArrRep(1 To 17)

    ArrFnd(1) = "(?[! ^s.…:;\!\?\*^13^m^n])([^13])"
    ArrRep(1) = "\1.^p"

etc.

    With rngContent.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True

        For i = LBound(ArrFnd) To UBound(ArrFnd)
            .Text = ArrFnd(i)
            .Replacement.Text = ArrRep(i)
            .Replacement.Highlight = True

            Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
                If rngContent.Paragraphs(1).Style.NameLocal <> "Head-ing_14pt" Then
                    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
                End If
            Loop
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

As I mentioned the idea is to use an array to perform multiple find and replace operations everywhere in the text except for paragraphs with a particular style (Heading_14pt). In other words to exclude this heading from the search area.
The macro starts an endless loop and does not stop. Please help!

Surely the style is "Heading_14pt" not "Head-ing_14pt"

.Wrap = wdFindContinue should be .Wrap = wdFindStop

Thank All for help!!!
